# optgroup select title of group

Tags: html, optgroup

I want to create a drop-down box with grouped items. It is for a database lookup HTML form that I am working with. Is there a way that I can select the group title, resulting in selection of all items in that particular group? For example, if the group title is 'German Cars' and has the items 'Mercedes' and 'Audi', on clicking 'German Cars', both German car companies should get selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your opt-groups a class you can select the class then access its children.

```
$('.german-cars').children();
```

If that's unavailable the alternative is a little slow. When you loop through all the optgroups and compare their text individually then grab that ones children.

*edit*: Fix selector.
And elaborating:

Then to select them on click you'd use:

```
$('.german-cars').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Assuming the element is set to multiple selection. Otherwise only the last car in the list would get selected.

**EDIT 2**

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbChZ/25/

These changes should work the way you're looking for.

```
$(function() {
    $('select optgroup').mousedown(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).children(':selected').length == $(this).children().length) {
            $(this).children().attr('selected', null);
        } else {
            $(this).children().attr('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });
    $('select option').mousedown(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
       e.preventDefault();
       $(this).attr('selected', ($(this).is(':selected'))? null : 'selected');                    
    });
});​
```

I've changed the events to mousedown so we can see the state of the elements before the browser has already handled the mousedown event. This allows us to check if they're all selected and if so deselect rather than select. And the same had to be done for the click event of the `option` so that it can prevent propagation on that event.

I'm not 100% sure of the browser compatability on this one though you may want to make sure it works in older IE's if you support them.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesnt work. Please refer to my code below:

JAVASCRIPT:

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
$("optgroup.german_cars").children();
$("optgroup.german_cars").click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).children().attr('selected','selected');
});
</script>

Comment: html:

<label style="vertical-align:top">Select a Car Company:</label>

<select multiple="multiple" size="10" id='sections'>
   <optgroup label='German Cars' class="german_cars">
       <option value='mercedes'>Mercedes</option>
       <option value='audi'>Audi</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label='Swiss Cars' class="swiss_cars">
       <option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>
       <option value='saab'>Saab</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>

Comment: Hmm, just tested seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mbChZ/3/ Just noticed that clicking the options fires the optgroup click event as well. So you'll need to also put a click handler on those and stop propagation after setting the state yourself. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbChZ/6/

Comment: It is working in the Fiddle, but unfortunately, its not working on my system. Sorry, I am a little new to this. It is a HTML file. Following is the complete code:

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
$(function() {
$('.german-cars').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).children().attr('selected', 'selected');
});
    $('select option').click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).attr('selected', ($(this).is(':selected'))? '' : 'selected');       
    });
});
</script>
</head>

Comment: <body>
<select multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup class="german-cars" label="test">
        <option value="0">One</option>
        <option value="1">Two</option>
        <option value="2">Three</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You have to close your jQuery include tag. So in your head <script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script> then open up a new script tag <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> //CODE HERE </script>

Comment: Also if you'd like to make it work for all optgroups you can give your `select` a class and do this $('.myselect optgroup') as opposed to the individual optgroup.

Comment: I have made the change that you suggested, group selection is working perfectly. But now, its not allowing me to select an item. I dont know why.

Comment: I fixed it by adding toggle: 

    $('select option').click(function(e) {
       e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).toggle(attr('selected', ($(this).is(':selected'))? '' : 'selected'));
    });

Is this the right way to do it?
Also, could you please tell me how do I toggle the group selection?

Comment: You seem to have worked really hard, dennmat! Thank you very much for your generous help and support! The updated code works really well. Its just that, when I add multiple groups, the first group doesnt get selected when I click on it. It works well for other groups though. Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/mbChZ/26/
Thanks again! I owe you a drink already!

Comment: Hey, no problem, and unfortunately the fiddle you sent me seems to work fine for all optgroups including the first, which browser are you using?

Comment: Unfortunately, its not working for me. I am using Firefox, the first optgroup isnt getting selected. I also tried Chrome, there all optgroups are getting selected (including the first one), but unselect optgroup is not working. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Not in any reliable way. The `optgroup` is just for grouping options, not for affecting functionality. But you could use a set of checkboxes instead of a `select` elements, and then you could have a checkbox for “German cars” and, e.g. indented below it, checkboxes for different German car models.

You could then deal with this in various ways. You could just handle the situation server-side, so that if “German cars” has been checked, the form handler acts as if each and every checkbox for a German car had been selected. Or you could additionally have a client-side handler for the “German cars” checkbox, so that checking it checks the individual checkboxes (but should it then uncheck them when unchecked)?